# Can someone explain what this op amp circuit achieves?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

In this schematic a line-level audio signal is passed in to R42 and out of the op amp. Can someone explain the effect of the op amp on the signal in this configuration?

[image]

Comment: Its a low-pass filter. Maybe sallen and key type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [Sallen-Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology) filter. It is a low pass filter, and if I have done my math correctly, it has a pole frequency of about 13.9kHz.

\$f=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}\$